# iPhone Camera is not working in react-native 0.55.4?

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, info.plist, react-native-camera

native-camera in my react-native app.

For this I am using [https://github.com/coretech/react-native-camera](http://react-native-camera)

After setup this module into my project, my app was crashed and it shows a **error message** in console like this

**[access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.**

Even I added the keys in info.plist for accessing camera in iOS.

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Your message to user when the photo library is accessed for the first time</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>uses photos</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>uses camera</string>
```

My System configuration: npm 6.1.0, react-native-cli: 2.0.1, react-native: 0.55.4, Mac OS 10.13.5, Xcode 9.3

Comment: clean project.... Run again

Comment: @ios Thank you for the reply,
I already did many times,its not working.

Comment: Refer these two links https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html.    https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2016/09/infoplist-privacy-settings-in-ios-10.html. And try again, all the best...

Comment: @ios bro I already check that one and updated in my code also. It is combination of iOS and React-Native.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I fix my issue by using this link 
https://steinar.io/building-your-own-camera-app-for-ios-with-react-native/